Processing the same array, dask.array is too slow compared to numpy.array
import BWStest as bws
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label
import dask.array
from tqdm import tqdm
CalWin = [7,25]
stack = []
thershold = 0.05
for i in range(5):
  image = np.random.rand(3000, 4000)
  dask_image = dask.array.from_array(image, chunks=(1000, 1000))
  stack.append(dask_image)
stacks = dask.array.stack(stack, axis=0)

npages,nlines,nwidths = np.shape(stacks)
RadiusRow=(CalWin[0] - 1) // 2
RadiusCol=(CalWin[1] -1 ) // 2
InitRow=(CalWin[0] + 1) // 2
InitCol=(CalWin[1] + 1) // 2
mlistack = dask.array.pad(dask.array.abs(stacks), ((0, 0), (RadiusRow, RadiusRow), (RadiusCol, RadiusCol)), mode='symmetric').compute()
meanmli = dask.array.mean(mlistack, axis=0)
nlines_EP,nwidths_EP = meanmli.shape
del meanmli
PixelInd = np.zeros((CalWin[0] * CalWin[1],nlines*nwidths), dtype=np.bool)
num = 0
compar_pixel = np.zeros((CalWin[0] * CalWin[1],nlines*nwidths))
for kk in tqdm(range(InitCol, nwidths_EP-RadiusCol), desc="Processing columns", ascii=' ='):
    for ll in tqdm(range(InitRow, nlines_EP-RadiusRow), desc="Processing rows", 
                  leave=False, ascii=' ='):
        Matrix = mlistack[:,ll-RadiusRow-1:ll+RadiusRow,kk-RadiusCol-1:kk+RadiusCol]
        # print(Matrix)
        Ref = Matrix[:,InitRow-1,InitCol-1]
        Xarray = np.tile(Ref[:, np.newaxis], (1, CalWin[0] * CalWin[1]))
        Matrix_T = np.transpose(Matrix, (0, 2, 1))
        Yarray = np.reshape(Matrix_T, (Matrix_T.shape[0], CalWin[0] * CalWin[1]))
        T = bws.BWS(Xarray, Yarray, thershold)
        SeedPoint = np.transpose(np.reshape(~T, (CalWin[1], CalWin[0])))
        LL = label(SeedPoint, 2)
        LL_flat = np.transpose(LL).flatten()
        compar_pixel[:,num] = (LL_flat == LL[InitRow - 1, InitCol - 1])
        PixelInd[:,num] = (LL_flat == LL[InitRow - 1, InitCol - 1])
        num = num + 1

the processing speed, it is probably 2400
dask version:
import BWStest as bws
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label
import dask.array
from tqdm import tqdm
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, progress
CalWin = [7,25]
stack = []
thershold = 0.05
for i in range(5):

    image = np.random.rand(3000, 4000)
    dask_image = dask.array.from_array(image, chunks=(1000, 1000))
    stack.append(dask_image) 
stacks = dask.array.stack(stack, axis=0)
npages,nlines,nwidths = np.shape(stacks)
RadiusRow=(CalWin[0] - 1) // 2
RadiusCol=(CalWin[1] -1 ) // 2
InitRow=(CalWin[0] + 1) // 2
InitCol=(CalWin[1] + 1) // 2
mlistack = dask.array.pad(dask.array.abs(stacks), ((0, 0), (RadiusRow, RadiusRow), (RadiusCol, RadiusCol)),mode='symmetric').compute()
meanmli = dask.array.mean(mlistack, axis=0)
nlines_EP,nwidths_EP = meanmli.shape
del meanmli

PixelInd = dask.array.zeros((CalWin[0] * CalWin[1],nlines*nwidths),
                                  chunks=(CalWin[0] * CalWin[1],2048*nlines),dtype=np.bool)
num = 0
compar_pixel = dask.array.zeros((CalWin[0] * CalWin[1],nlines*nwidths),
                                  chunks=(CalWin[0] * CalWin[1],2048*nlines),dtype=np.bool)
for kk in tqdm(range(InitCol, nwidths_EP-RadiusCol), desc="Processing columns",ascii=' ='):
    for ll in tqdm(range(InitRow, nlines_EP-RadiusRow), desc="Processing rows",leave=False, ascii=' ='):
         Matrix = mlistack[:,ll-RadiusRow-1:ll+RadiusRow,kk-RadiusCol-1:kk+RadiusCol]
         Ref = Matrix[:,InitRow-1,InitCol-1]
         Xarray = dask.array.tile(Ref[:, np.newaxis], (1, CalWin[0] * CalWin[1]))
         Matrix_T = dask.array.transpose(Matrix, (0, 2, 1))
         Yarray = dask.array.reshape(Matrix_T, (Matrix_T.shape[0], CalWin[0] * 
         CalWin[1]))
         T = dask.array.from_array(bws.BWS(Xarray.compute(), Yarray.compute(), thershold))
         SeedPoint = dask.array.transpose(dask.array.reshape(~T, (CalWin[1], CalWin[0])))
         LL = dask.array.from_array(label(SeedPoint.compute(), 2))
         LL_flat = dask.array.Array.flatten(dask.array.transpose(LL))
         compar_pixel[:,num] = (LL_flat == LL[InitRow - 1, InitCol - 1])
         PixelInd[:,num] = (LL_flat == LL[InitRow - 1, InitCol - 1])
         num = num + 1

the processing speed, it is probably 40
From the results, it appears that dask processing is very slow
can you give me some suggestion,thank you very much
this is the bws function
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata
def BWS(Xarrar, Yarray, threshold):
  n, m = Xarrar.shape
  rank = rankdata(np.vstack((Xarrar, Yarray)), axis=0)
  xrank = np.sort(rank[0:n,:], axis=0)
  yrank = np.sort(rank[n::,:], axis=0)
  temp = np.arange(1, n+1)[:,np.newaxis]*np.ones((1,m))
  tempx = (xrank - 2.0*temp) ** 2
  tempy = (yrank - 2.0*temp) ** 2
  temp  = temp/(n+1) * (1-temp/(n+1)) * 2 * n 
  BX    = 1/n * np.sum(tempx / temp, axis=0)
  BY    = 1/n * np.sum(tempy / temp, axis=0)
  # test statistic
  B = 1/2*(BX + BY)
  if threshold ==0.05:
    if n == 5:
        b = 2.533
    elif n == 6:
        b = 2.552
    elif n == 7:
        b = 2.620
    elif n == 8:
        b = 2.564   
    elif n == 9:
        b = 2.575     
    elif n == 10:
        b = 2.583
    else:
        b = 2.493
  else:
    b = 3.880

  H = (B >=b)
  H = np.transpose(H)
  return H

As I will be dealing with very large matrices in the future, I have to use dask to store data. However, as a beginner in dask, I want to use dask to achieve the same processing speed as numpy
